# ip configuration could not resolved (no available address, timeout)

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux

I am running virtual box fusion with multiple VM's on it. on all the VM's i am facing an error when i tried to connect my VM with DHCP.

```
 Error: connection activation failed: IP configuration could not be reserved(no available addresses, timeout, etc.)
```

Comment: You’re probably referring to VMware Fusion...? Either way, what is the VMs’ network configuration? Are they set to bridged or NAT? Is the host system a MacBook? Is it connected to the network wirelessly?